# Can't get this query to group properly

Tags: sql-server

The tEmplHistory table has chronological records for employees. Each record has a start date that indicates when the status changes for that employee. I need to pull out all the records for all employees closest to but not exceeding some given date. The record for each employee will the one immediately before that given date for that employee. In the output I need the EmplHistoryID, that's all. This where I'm stuck:

[image: This is where I'm stuck]
Here is the table:

```
USE foo
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tEmplHistory]    Script Date: 1/1/2017 6:12:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tEmplHistory](
    [EmplHistoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EmplStatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Comment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DateStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EmplID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tEmplHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmplHistoryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Here is some data:

```
INSERT
    [dbo].[tEmplHistory]
    ( [EmplHistoryID], [StartDate], [EmplStatusID], [Comment], [DateStamp], [EmplID] )
VALUES
    (9375, CAST(0x0000A6EE0104A007 AS DateTime), 1, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE0104A007 AS DateTime), 2768),
    (9376, CAST(0x0000A58000000000 AS DateTime), 1, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE010B2D97 AS DateTime), 2768),
    (9377, CAST(0x0000A43100000000 AS DateTime), 1, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE010B481D AS DateTime), 2768),
    (9378, CAST(0x0000A58100000000 AS DateTime), 1, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE010B591F AS DateTime), 2768),
    (9379, CAST(0x0000A57F00000000 AS DateTime), 1, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE010B6F5C AS DateTime), 2768),
    (9380, CAST(0x0000A57E00000000 AS DateTime), 1, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE010B7AB7 AS DateTime), 2768),
    (9381, CAST(0x0000A58100000000 AS DateTime), 1, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE010B9343 AS DateTime), 2768),
    (9382, CAST(0x0000A58200000000 AS DateTime), 2, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE01188D3E AS DateTime), 2767),
    (9383, CAST(0x0000A57F00000000 AS DateTime), 2, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE011903FF AS DateTime), 2767),
    (9384, CAST(0x0000A57E00000000 AS DateTime), 2, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE01194FF5 AS DateTime), 2767),
    (9385, CAST(0x0000A58100000000 AS DateTime), 1, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE012780A6 AS DateTime), 2),
    (9386, CAST(0x0000A58000000000 AS DateTime), 2, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE01278D59 AS DateTime), 2),
    (9387, CAST(0x0000A57F00000000 AS DateTime), 3, NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE0127A45A AS DateTime), 2)

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tEmplHistory] OFF
    GO
```

For this sample data I need three EmplHistoryID values:

```
9386 for EmplID = 2
9383 for EmplID = 2767
9376 for EmplID 2768
```

Comment: I recommend typing the query by hand instead of using the Query Designer - the designer is not expressive enough for anything more beyond trivial queries.

Comment: Where is the "given date" that you want to compare to the StartDate?  I don't see this included in your table, so am I to assume its a variable parameter you would want to pass in each time you make this query you are trying to create?

Comment: Do you have `employees` table ?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pull out all the records for all employees closest to but not exceeding some given date.

Your question is made more difficult to answer by the obfuscated dates in your sample data.  In 20 years of T-SQL work, that's the first time I've seen binary values explicitly converted to `datetime`.  Usually, literal values are supplied as strings.

The basic form of your query is not complicated, though.  You want *all* records before a date certain, not just one, so

```
select * from tEmplHistory where StartDate <  '1/1/1990'
```

or whatever date you wish to specify.

But maybe that's not what you mean?  Maybe you mean ***the*** single row for each employee prior to and nearest a date certain?  For that you want a correlated subquery:

```
select * from tEmplHistory as H where exists (
    select 1 from tEmplHistory 
    where EmplHistoryID = H.EmplHistoryID
    and StartDate <  '1/1/1990' 
    group by EmplHistoryID
    having max(StartDate) = H.StartDate
)
```

The subquery finds the latest start date prior to the given date for each `EmplHistoryID`.  That date, and the EmplHistoryID are joined to the rows in the outer table (which in this case is the same table).

Comment: Your beef is with SSMS. It generated the script.

Answer (score 0):

For each employee you want the latest record before a given date. So you select records before that date, rank your records per employee by date and keep the latest:

```
select emplid, emplhistoryid
from
(
  select 
    emplid, 
    emplhistoryid, 
    row_number() over(partition by emplid order by datestamp desc) as rn 
  from templhistory eh
  where datestamp <= '20161231'
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to pull the employees whose status changed before 2016-01-01 the below would work .

```
    SELECT EMPLHISTORYID ,EMPID FROM 
(
    SELECT EMPLHISTORYID,[EmplID] AS EMPID,
    STARTDATE,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [EmplID] ORDER BY StarttDate   Desc )   as RNK
FROM [dbo].[tEmplHistory]
WHERE startDATE <='2016-01-01 00:00:00'
 )A
WHERE A.RNK=1
```